Error in installing python library for computer vision
I am trying to install opencv-python using the command pip install opencv-contrib-python but after some part of downloading,it says
ERROR: THESE PACKAGES DO NOT MATCH THE HASHES FROM THE REQUIREMENTS FILE. If you have updated the package versions, please update the hashes. Otherwise, examine the package contents carefully; someone may have tampered with them.
unknown package:
    Expected sha256 47ec3160dae75f70e099b286d1a2e086d20dac8b06e759f60eaf867e6bdecba7
         Got        e091e7d60388b8d6b7e08c4a396b7705498eafee5e70e3cae1705c9db6c6a83f

I am looking into some other commands but they are not working.It installs properly when using pip install opencv-python but I have to use contrib files

How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users? - One of the first steps in solving a problem should always be to google your error message.

This issue can be solved by updating pip: pip install --upgrade pip  and then clearing your pip cache using pip cache purge.
